# Go to a specific part of a page from another page - Anchor Position and jQuery?

Tags: php, html, anchor

I have completely no idea where to start so I apologise about the lack of code presented to you.

My problem is - I have a page of information, ordered by ID (gathered from the database). These ID's are referenced from another page to which the user clicks on a link and it takes them to the page with the information on, how ever, there could be potentially hundreds of ID's on that page - So I need to reference each specific ID so when the user clicks, it will take them to the exact position of the ID.

I understand its something like localhost:8888/index.html#id3 etc..

But i'm struggling to understand how to reference for a PHP Variable.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect that PHP reference at the end, after a story about JavaScript. You cannot refer to the `hash` (`#id3`) through PHP, because the hash isn't sent with the request. If you want to get a reference to it, you have to expand the ID to the quesry string: `index.html?id=id3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [anchors](http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html), so for example, on the page where you list your information, attach an anchor to it such as `#id1`, then on your links page, you would place the `#id1` at the end of the url `results.html?#id3`